# group by expression must contain one column that is not an outer reference

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Would somebody please take a look at this? I am trying to sum the total weight of all of our skus, but I need them to group either by foreign or domestic. SQL 2008 server.

```
Select 
  IMSYS01.on_hand_qty * IMSYS01.piece_weight,
  IMSYS01.sku_no,
  case when(imsys01.warehouse = '109') then 'foreign' else 'domestic' end as 'vLocation'
From
  IMSYS01 IMSYS01
Where
  (IMSYS01.sku_no < '99999' And
  IMSYS01.velo_code <> 'X')
Group By
 IMSYS01.on_hand_qty * IMSYS01.piece_weight, 'vLocation', IMSYS01.sku_no
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, the dreaded use of single quotes for an identifier.  Don't use single quotes for an identifier.  This is what you want:

```
Select IMSYS01.on_hand_qty * IMSYS01.piece_weight,
       IMSYS01.sku_no,
       (case when(imsys01.warehouse = '109') then 'foreign' else 'domestic' end) as vLocation
From IMSYS01 IMSYS01
Where (IMSYS01.sku_no < '99999' And IMSYS01.velo_code <> 'X')
Group By IMSYS01.on_hand_qty * IMSYS01.piece_weight, 
         (case when(imsys01.warehouse = '109') then 'foreign' else 'domestic' end),
         IMSYS01.sku_no;
```

This is a great example of why you should *never* use single quotes for identifiers.  It causes confusion.  SQL Server supports other methods, but you don't even need to escape `vlocation`.  It is a fine identifier just by itself.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it was something simple!